# If $A,B$ are two $n\times n$ invertible matrices, then $B^T x = Ax$ only when $x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following true?

> If $A,B$ are two $n\times n$ invertible matrices, then the only solution to $B^T x = Ax$ is zero.

I suspect this to be false but I couldn't come up with a specific example since we have $n\times n$. I do have one counterexample for $2\times 2$.

I am thinking about looking at the dimension of $\ker(B^T - A)$, or $\ker(A^{-1}B^T - I)$. But it doesn't work because sum of invertible matrices might be non-invertible.

Comment: What if $B=A^T$?

Comment: @edm Oh...right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then so is $A^T$. So you might consider the case when $B = A^T$. Or you might consider the case when $A = B = I$.

So no, it is not true.

Comment: What we add a restriction that $B\neq A \neq A^T$?

Comment: That it is still not true. For a quick counterexample, suppose you're in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for instance, and $A$ is the zero matrix except for $1$ in the $(1,1)$ spot, and $B$ is zero except for $1$ in the $(3,3)$ spot. Then $A [0,1,0] = B [0, 1, 0] = A^T [0, 1, 0] = 0$, for instance.

Comment: shouldn't the matrices be n by n and invertible?

Comment: @gbox whoops! Then have $A$ be the identity matrix with an additional $1$ in the $(3,1)$ spot, and $B$ be the identity matrix with additional $1$s in the $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ spots. Then $A [ 0, 1 , 0] = A^T [ 0, 1, 0] = B [0, 1 , 0] = [0, 1, 0]$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to *disprove* the statement, you do not need to find a counter example that is $n$ by $n$. One counter example that is a $2$ by $2$ matrix is enough.

As edm pointed out in the comments, taking $B = A^T$ is a clear counterexample.

Comment: Yeah. The original question was actually asking for "every $n$". My bad. But $B=A^T$ makes sense haha.

Comment: Yes, and the negation of $\forall \dots$ is $\exists \neg \dots$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)^t$. Then for any matrix $A$ it is easy to check $Ax={}$first column of $A$.

Now it is a question of constructing $B^t$ and $A$ to be non-singular matrices with the same first columns but otherwise different.